# Get the start date and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the start date and end date. help me please
I have such a table:

```
| login| date_start| date_end  |
|user1 | 2022-01-01| 2022-01-01|
|user1 | 2022-01-02| 2022-01-02|
|user1 | 2022-01-03| 2022-01-03|
|user2 | 2022-01-05| 2022-01-05|
|user2 | 2022-01-06| 2022-01-06|
|user1 | 2022-02-24| 2022-02-24|
|user1 | 2022-02-25| 2022-02-25|
|user1 | 2022-02-26| 2022-02-26|
```

expected result:

```
user1 2022-01-01 - 2022-01-03
user2 2022-01-05 - 2022-01-06
user1 2022-02-24 - 2022-02-26
```

Comment: You can ask a new question with the new data, someone will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_start) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login ORDER BY date_start) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT login, MIN(date_start) AS date_start, MAX(date_end) AS date_end
FROM cte
GROUP BY login, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY MIN(date_start);
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90b24c9290e48b8da5c2df0c5eb0c033).

Comment: thx. but the result is not what I expected. look at the link. with real data [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e9e2c3553ec61fc4678b4114d6eedd6)

Comment: Now you are asking a different question with different data.

Comment: I am very sorry that I expressed myself incorrectly. I need to get periods